# Shulker Farm Failure Rate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a shulker farm following the design by [devilmok](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaD8Qyi942Y). Centered on the trapped shulker, there are 4 nether portals with 17x17 portal blocks. These are spaced apart with blocks in between to allow shulkers to teleport to. This image taken from devilmok's video shows the side view.

[image: design side view]

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shulker#Post-generation), when the shulker wants to duplicate, it chooses a random block within 17x17x17 space centered on itself and tries teleporting to it, repeating if the block is invalid up to 4 more times (with a total of 5 times). Since there are 8 17x17 planes next to portal blocks it can teleport to, this gives a duplicate failure rate of  p = (1 - 8/17)<sup>5</sup> = 0.0416.

Shulkers have 30 health and deals 4 damage per hit. Since shulkers duplicate after being hit as long as they have over half health, the shulker can fail to duplicate 4 times before breaking the farm.

To calculate the mean time between failure, we calculate the average number of hits it takes to see 4 consecutive failures. [This turns out](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Eginsparg/physics/INFO295/mh.pdf) to be (1 + p + p<sup>2</sup> + p<sup>3</sup>)/p<sup>4</sup> = 348400. If each hit takes ~2 seconds, this equates to ~8 days.

In minecraft 1.17, 8 days sounds about right: the farm never broke. But recently after I upgraded to 1.18.2, it broke *4* times on me within a week. Did something change? Or is my calculation off and I just got really lucky in the past? Or am I unbelievably unlucky?